# My Netbeans Editor Lags Heavily (Running on Mac, Programming in C)

Tags: macos, netbeans

I'm a student who uses Netbeans on Mac to Program in C. Due to my previous experience with Java, I really like the feeling of Netbeans IDE. However, I recently noticed, as my projects gets longer and longer, simply coding the plain text is starting to lag heavily, inside the IDE editor.

For example, when I type in any words, even if just comments, if feels like it takes the computer a second or two to respond to every type. Things get even worse when I try to scroll up and down in my code, the response takes a long time, making it feel really bad.

I thought this might be a problem that the IDE haven't been given enough memory. However, after increasing the memory given to the program, it still lags heavily.

Is this all due to the fact running Netbeans to program in C is a bad idea? Or is it something else going wrong in my case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `C` language. It is only about NETBEANS or your ENVIROMENT. Why are you spamming TAGs?

Comment: I've had this same problem with Netbeans before. I am not a fan of Netbeans. Get a new IDE. You're on a mac, use Xcode.

Comment: try increasing the heap size

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

The result is kind of clear. There just wasn't really any viable plan to make it work...

I started working on another computer instead. It seems mac just don't really want to work with netbeans, especially about C.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (MacOS Monterey) the problem was the font size. The more I increased it, the worse the IDE would work.

Over 14 font size the lag is pretty extreme.
I would recommend using another IDE as it looks like this problem has not been fixed even in the latest version.